# How to replace a catalog price rule by a cart price rule when adding a specific product in cart?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I have a catalog price rule which give a 25% discount in all product based on a customer group.

I want to create a cart price rule which give a 30% discount in all cart when a product with SKU "ABO1" (this product won't be discount) is added to the cart but it needs to override the 25% discount of the catalog price rule.

How can i manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be as simple as giving the 30% cart rule a higher priority in the rule (bottom of rule information) and then in actions set stop further rule precessing to yes (bottom of actions tab)?